# Перспективная камера. Lwjgl 3

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Доброе время суток.
Возникла проблема по созданию перспективной камеры.
Вырезка из кода:

```
glViewport(0,0,1024,840);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(30f ,1024f / 840f, 0.001f,100);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Выкидывает исключение:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glMultMatrix(Ljava/nio/FloatBuffer;)V
at org.lwjgl.util.glu.Project.gluPerspective(Project.java:218)
at org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU.gluPerspective(GLU.java:286)
```

При работе с glOrtho все нормально.
В чем может заключатся проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В LWJGL 3 была убран данный метод. Взятая от 2.93 lwjgl-util не подходит. Так как 3 версия была "облегчена", реализацию Perspective нужно писать самому.

p.s: Вопрос решен. Можно его удалить...